# Custom FFMpeg Build with QSV, CUDA and VAAPI that can also run on other servers and directories

Tags: ffmpeg, compilation, gpu, vaapi

Since I am starting with my first build experience with FFMpeg. I want build a custom version of FFMpeg with IntelHD GPU (QSV) and Nvidia GPU (NVENC) and VAAPI support, which should also run later on other Linux (Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04) computers with corresponding GPUs (IntelHD + GPU).
So I would like to ask the following questions:

- Do the corresponding graphics cards (IntelHD and Nvidia) have to be available on the server where i want compile FFMpeg and do their drivers have to be installed? Or is it not necessary ?
- If the graphics card drivers have to be installed, do the card drivers still have to be installed on another server, or are the drivers compiled accordingly?
- Which configuration settings have to be made to run the FFmpeg binary on different directorys on third (foreign) servers, like /home/anotherfolder/underfolder/ffmpeg ?

Answer (score 0):

Building FFMPEG doesn't requires any GPU or Drivers installed, and no any special configuration settings other than have all dependencies satisfied in that OS.